# Pay Pal API call, get payments

Tags: c#, rest, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I need to get all the payments of our paypal account. I created the application and get all payments record over paypal API [Using this API method](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#list-payment-resources).

Here is my code snippet.

```
private String GetPayPalAccessToken()
{
    _payPalConfig.Add("mode", "live");
    _payPalConfig.Add("endpoint",_url);
     OAuthTokenCredential tokenCredential = new OAuthTokenCredential(_clientId, _clientSecret, _payPalConfig);
     return tokenCredential.GetAccessToken();
}

Dictionary<string, string> TempConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
TempConfig.Add("count", "10");
TempConfig.Add("start_time", "2015-01-01T00:00:00Z");
TempConfig.Add("end_time", "2015-01-18T00:00:00Z");
TempConfig.Add("sort_by", "create_time");

APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(GetPayPalAccessToken());
apiContext.Config = _payPalConfig;
PaymentHistory paymentHistory = Payment.List(apiContext, TempConfig);
```

and I get 200 status and zero results.(Count = 0,but I can see 10 payments on paypal interface).

Please anyone can help me to find the issue. because status is 200 means I didn't do any stupid thing. What would be the reason for this issue?

Thank you
Gayan

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that call is only see payments that have been setup using the REST API so you can see their status and potentially execute them accordingly.

If you're trying to pull any/all transactions from your PayPal account, the same as it shows up in your transaction history at paypal.com, you'll want to use the [TransactionSearch API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/).